# Multiple X-UA-Compatible meta tags in SharePoint masterpage one of it for webpart

Tags: 2010, html, ie8

I have the code `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>`  in my master page so certain things will work. However I have a twitter webpart which doesn't work in IE 8 so I need to change it to IE=10. Is there anyway I can use something like this for a particular web part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it, but this could be helpful.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5, IE=8, IE=9, IE=10" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some jquery.  The caution is to make sure you don't break the SP UI when you make the change. #soTesting. This is working in my 2010 site now. In 2013 the doctype is set to HTML so the issue would not happen.

```
if ($('meta[http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible]', top.document).attr('content') == 'IE=8') {
    $('meta[http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"]', top.document).attr('content', 'IE=8,IE=9,IE=10,Edge');
    $('meta[http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"]').attr('content', 'IE=8,IE=9,IE=10,Edge');
}
```